# How to convert _io.TextIOWrapper to string?

Tags: python, string, file

I read the text format using below code,

```
f = open("document.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8-sig')
f.read()
```

But the type of `f` is `_io.TextIOWrapper`. But I need type as string to move on.

Please help me to convert  `_io.TextIOWrapper` to string.

Comment: Please read the tutorial provided in Python documentation. What you want is `txt = f.read()`.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use the output of `f.read()`.

```
string = f.read()
```

I think your confusion is that `f` will be turned into a string just by calling its method `.read()`, but that's not the case. I don't think it's even possible for builtins to do that.

For reference, `_io.TextIOWrapper` is the class of an open text file. See [the documentation for `io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

---

By the way, best practice is to use a `with`-statement for opening files:

```
with open("document.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    string = f.read()
```

Answer (score -3):

This is good:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

This is not good:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

Comment: Can please you edit your answer to add additional explanation on the differences and why one method is preferable?

Answer (score -4):

It's not a super elegant solution but it works for me

```
def extractPath(innie):
    iggy = str(innie)

    getridofme ="<_io.TextIOWrapper name='"
    getridofmetoo ="' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"

    iggy = iggy.replace(getridofme, "")
    iggy = iggy.replace(getridofmetoo, "")
    #iggy.trim()

    print(iggy)

    return iggy
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. This is super overcomplicated. You can just do `innie.name`. But that's not what OP's asking; they're asking how to *read* the file.